# Angular - Update Every Property Of An Object After Resource Save

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc

I'm passing an object to a resource, which makes some database updates that could change multiple properties of the object (beyond the changes made in the UI).

If I update the properties individually, the changes are reflected in the HTML.  But if I try to update the entire object, the changes are not reflected.

So, this works:

```
myResource.doSomething(item)
    .$promise
    .then(function (response) {
        item.Color = response.Result.Color;
        item.Shape = response.Result.Shape;
    });
```

But this doesn't:

```
myResource.doSomething(item)
    .$promise
    .then(function (response) {
        item = response.Result;
    });
```

What's the best way to update every property of the object?

In case it helps, here's my resource (posts to an MVC controller which returns JSON of the updated object):

```
app.factory('myResource', function ($resource) {
    return {
        doSomething: function (item) {
            return $resource('/Something/Do/:Id', { Id: item.Id }).save();
        }
    };
});`
```

EDIT: To clarify, the item is part of a collection bound to an ng-repeat directive, e.g.:

```
<tr ng-repeat="item in items" >
    <td>
        <a ng-click="doSomething(item)" >Do Something</a>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Wouldn't Object.assign(item, response.Result)  not work?

Comment: I haven't used that method before (new to Angular).  When I try this ...

Object.assign(item, response.Result);

... compiler tells me "Property Assign does not exist on type 'ObjectConstructor'".

If I try ...

item.assign(item, response.Result);

... angular tells me "item.assign is not a function".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason this doesn't work:

```
myResource.doSomething(item)
    .$promise
    .then(function (response) {
        item = response.Result;
    });
```

Is because what you're essentially doing is overwriting the **local variable** named `item`.

I don't know exactly how your items list is filled as you haven't shown the Controller/Component code, but let me just show you how it should work with comments, hopefully you can make sense of it that way :)

```js
angular
  .module("app", [])
  .controller("myController", function($timeout, myResource) {
    var _this = this;
    _this.loadingItems = true;
 
    // Fake loading the items
    $timeout(function() {
      _this.items = [
        { "Id": 1, "Name": "Some Name" },
        { "Id": 2, "Name": "Other Name" },
        { "Id": 3, "Name": "Yet another Name" },
        { "Id": 4, "Name": "Final Name" },
      ];
      _this.loadingItems = false;
    }, 500);
    
    _this.doSomething = function(item) {
        item.sending = true;
       myResource.doSomething(item)
        .then(function(newItem) {
          // Here's where the magic happens
          // First find where the existing items is at in the array
          var existingIndex = _this.items.indexOf(item);
          // Replace the item with the one from the server
          _this.items.splice(existingIndex, 1, newItem);
        });
    }
    
  })
  .factory('myResource', function ($timeout) {
    return {
        doSomething: function (item) {
            // Fake sending something to the server which returns a new Item object
            return $timeout(function() {
               return { Id: item.Id, "Name": "New name returned by server!" };
            }, 250);
        }
    };
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.8/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="app">

  <!-- Notice the 'as vm' on the controller to put the controller on the scope as 'vm' -->
  <div ng-controller="myController as vm">
    <p ng-if="vm.loadingItems">Busy loading items</p>
    
    <table ng-if="!vm.loadingItems">
      <tr ng-repeat="item in vm.items track by item.Id">
        <td>
          {{item.Name}}
        </td>
        <td>
          <a href="javascript:void(0);" ng-if="!item.sending" ng-click="vm.doSomething(item)">Do Something</a>
          <span ng-if="item.sending">Working...<span>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>

  </div>

</div>
```

I really hope this helps! Otherwise I spent way too much time typing this :)

Comment: So, if my page has an ng-repeat directive with a collection of items, with each item containing ng-click="doSomething(item)", how I can pass "objectThatContainsAnItem" to the controller rather than "item"?  If objectThatContainsAnItem is the collection of items, I'm not sure if I want to pass that, since it contains potentially hundreds of items.

Comment: The collection of items should already be wrapped in a containing item each. Can you update your question to include the part where the items collection is created that you ng-repeat through? Then I can update my answer to reflect the changes.

Comment: I've updated the answer to show how I think you should handle your situation.

Comment: Thanks so much.  Worked like a charm.  Really appreciate it.

Comment: Glad to have been of help! One final note though, if you're feeling adventurous. It would be better to not use a `<div>` with ng-controller, but instead create a new `component`. You can re-use most of the code though.